# How can I run a websocket server in next js custom server in dev mode

Tags: node.js, websocket, next.js

Assuming I want to run a custom next js server, and to accept websocket connections on that same server, how can I avoid clobbering the next js dev server hot reloading which is also using websockets on the same server...

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const WebSocket = require("ws")
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = createServer((req, res) => handle(req, res, parse(req.url, true)))
    // pass the same server instance that is used by next js to the websocket server
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })

    wss.on("connection", async function connection(ws) {
      console.log('incoming connection', ws);    
      ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('connection closed', wss.clients.size);
      };
    });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port} and ws://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

I believe this server should work in the production built version, so that the websocket server is created on the same server instance used to handle next js requests, but when I try to do this, the hot module reloading stops working, and errors appear in the chrome dev tools console because websocket connections it expects to be handled by webpack are now being handled by my custom websocket server.

How can I somehow route websocket connections for dev server to next and webpack and others to my own handler?

I know I can run my websocket server on another port, but I want to run it on the same server instance and same port as next js.

Comment: I know you mentioned that you want to run WS on the same server instance and port as that of Next.js, how about using a http-proxy to forward your custom WS requests to your WS server?

Comment: @PsyGik so that would mean running WS server on it's own port, and Next on another, then http-proxy on a third that ties them together? It would work I expect (not sure about details of proxying WS) but I was hoping to do something simpler so I can start one server on one port.

Comment: You'll need only 2 servers. 1. Next.js on it's own port. 2. WS server on it's own port. Then use something like [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) in your Next.js custom server to forward your WS requests to your custom WS server.

Comment: To make DX simpler, you can use npm-run-all or something similar to start all of your services in one go..

Comment: I actually discovered that I can start the websocket server from within `next.config.js` which is weird I know, but works. I really wanted to avoid assigning another port though

Comment: Assuming this is Next.js 12, you can maybe forward requests to `_next/webpack-hmr` to the next handler as mentioned in the [upgrading docs](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/docs/upgrading.md#nextjs-hmr-connection-now-uses-a-websocket)? and still manage to run everything on a single port...

Comment: @PsyGik that's interesting, but I think it's already doing that pretty much `const server = createServer((req, res) => handle(req, res, parse(req.url, true)))` - when creating the server I first pass all requests to the next handler

Comment: I think this might lead to an answer: https://github.com/websockets/ws#multiple-servers-sharing-a-single-https-server

Answer (score 12):

So the trick is to create a websocket server with noServer property set to true, and then listen to the server upgrade event, and depending on the pathname, do nothing to allow next js to do it's thing, or pass the request on to the websocket server we created...

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true })

server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
    const { pathname } = parse(req.url, true);
    if (pathname !== '/_next/webpack-hmr') {
        wss.handleUpgrade(req, socket, head, function done(ws) {
            wss.emit('connection', ws, req);
        });
    }
});
```

... all together something like this ...

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const WebSocket = require("ws")
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = createServer((req, res) => handle(req, res, parse(req.url, true)))
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ noServer: true })

    wss.on("connection", async function connection(ws) {
      console.log('incoming connection', ws);
      ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('connection closed', wss.clients.size);
      };
    });

    server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
        const { pathname } = parse(req.url, true);
        if (pathname !== '/_next/webpack-hmr') {
            wss.handleUpgrade(req, socket, head, function done(ws) {
                wss.emit('connection', ws, req);
            });
        }
    });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port} and ws://localhost:${port}`)
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @PsyGik for helping me get to this solution

Comment: This method does not work on nextjs 14, is there anything you would change about this setup? I'm using react-use-websocket on client and when it tries to connect the connection instantly closes, the ws open event never even triggers. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer to create a webSocket server on Next.js by using an api route instead of creating a custom server.

###### /pages/api/websocketserverinit.js:

```
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const SocketHandler = async (req, res) => {
    if (res.socket.server.wss) {
        console.log('Socket is already running')
    } else {
        console.log('Socket is initializing')
        const server = res.socket.server
        const wss = new WebSocketServer({ noServer: true })
        res.socket.server.wss = wss
        
        server.on('upgrade', (req, socket, head) => {
            console.log("upgrade", req.url)
        
            if (!req.url.includes('/_next/webpack-hmr')) {
                wss.handleUpgrade(req, socket, head, (ws) => {
                    wss.emit('connection', ws, req);
                });
            }

        });

        wss.on('connection', (ws)=> {
            console.log("connection", ws);
            ws.on('message', (data) => {
                console.log('received: %s', data);
            })

            ws.send('something');
        });

    }
    res.end()
}

export default SocketHandler
```

You will have to call the api route to start the websocket server from the client (or server init script):

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/websocketserverinit")
```

And then connect to it:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000")
```

Not super nice, but may be useful in some case

Comment: Can anyone attest that this works if deployed on a permanent connection (not serverless) like heroku or railway?

Comment: Another thing I just realized. Would each user be creating a ws server with a http request? Isn't there a way to create a global ws server at deploy time?

Comment: @GermanJablo This solution takes that into account by only creating a ws server once--if you load /websocketserverinit a second time, it will recognize there is already a server running (res.socket.server.wss) and not startup a server.